# Import ant design css files from node modules in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

According to the documentation you can import CSS files from a static folder which should be in the root directory but I want to import CSS from node_modules because I have extended ant.design and created my own package.

Adding the CSS file to the _app.js page still gives me the following error

```
./node_modules/antd/es/button/style/index.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-npm
Location: node_modules\antd\es\button\style\css.js
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    ["import", {
      "libraryName": "antd",
      "libraryDirectory": "es",
      "style": "css"
    }] // `style: true` for less
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think you need the antd tag instead of ant, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/antd/info

Comment: I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62726214/how-to-config-ant-design-in-next-js-with-custom-theme-support-css-module-featu) and it worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to config Ant Design in Next.js with custom theme & support CSS Module feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62726214/how-to-config-ant-design-in-next-js-with-custom-theme-support-css-module-featu)